# How to catch the element of external library using jest in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, element-ui

I'm using dropdown element from external library ElementUI in my VueJS project. And I'm trying to test this dropdown using Jest. But the problem is that it's impossible to find this element in jest like a normal tag (e.g. wrapper.find(tag, class or id)). I tried to catch like class - ".el-dropdown", like tag "el-dropdown", but didn't succeed. How could I dynamically catch this element to test it?

Answer (score 1):

I've succeed putting ref inside of  element -  and then in jest you can do something like this - wrapper.find({ ref: "item_1"}) and this will work!